# Zabbix fail message after second fail

Tags: zabbix

I have got a little problem with actions in zabbix and maybe you could help me to resolve this one.

I already have action whitch sends me email messages if any trigger changed status from OK to problem, but it's a lot of mesaages all day. I want to modify that action to send messages only if the trigger is in problem status for example for 10 minutes. I know how to set trigger to change status after 5 fails (for example) but that does not solve my problem.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you configure the default operation step duration of 60 seconds and tell it to send the message on the 11th step, then Zabbix will send the email if the problem has been active for 10 minutes, like so:

[image]

Also, you might wish to see [Zabbix documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/notifications/action/escalations) on escalations.